# Override Font-Awesome Icon with Bootstrap's Icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How would I override the font-awesome "icon-user" icon with the bootstrap one?

This is my header:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Blah Blah Blah</title>

  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:bold">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before closing head tag add this

```
<style type="text/css">    
.icon-user:before {
  content: "";
}
.icon-user {background-image: url("url/to/your/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png"); width: 14px; display: inline-block; background-position: -168px 0;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since font awesome is actually overriding your bootstrap, you have to override the override.

Fontawesome adds a bunch of css to the icon class, but the most important are:

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
font-family: FontAwesome;
background-image: none;
background-position: 0 0;
background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

You need to set them back to what they were, this is the originals:

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
display: inline-block;
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
margin-top: 1px;
line-height: 14px;
vertical-align: text-top;
background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
background-position: 14px 14px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

But most importantly, each bootstrap icon has a specific positioning. You have to set this back too.

```
.icon-user {
background-position: -168px 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that stop me from using the other font-awesome icons?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to change the order of your style sheets. The one called last takes precedence, unless the preceding rules are more specific. See the spec on cascading styles http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the `font-awesome.min.css`?  Just do a "find" on icon-user and comment out the CSS there.  It should just hide the font-awesome icon and possibly show the Bootstrap one in it's place.  One will not overwrite the other if there's not one to overwrite.

`.icon-user:before{content:"\f007"}`